# passing data between browser's javascript and activity

Tags: javascript, android, browser

How do we pass and receive data between browser's html/javascript and an Activity? 
I am able to call an activity from an html file from the Android browser by using a scheme in manifest. i-e . Now I want the activity to return data which I can then display/use on the web page's html. I am aware that you can use a Web View with in your app and call javascript functions etc to pass/receive data. Is it something I can also do from the Android Browser and my app (Activity)?

Comment: can you post the code which you are using to call activity from html file? I am assuming you are passing and intent and then using function startActivity() .  if so, you can use startActivityForResult() instead.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<a href="mysch://myapi/task1"> Do Task 1 </a>
</body>  .. Inside the manifest  <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="mysch" />
            </intent-filter>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is a part of your android application, then yes you can handle it the same way as Android Webview.

Following peice of code shall direct all the HTML being loaded in the Android browser to Android activity.

```
webContents.loadUrl("javascript:window.JavascriptInterface.ShowHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");

catch it in the class

class JavaScriptInterface {
        CloseableActivity activity;
}
```

Comment: I am not talking about the browser part of the application. It is about passing/getting data from the Android Browser app to my app.

Comment: That might not be possible as it would pose a security threat, if a normal application can capture all the events of Android Browser.